# Difference in Python 3 between `int( x / y )` and `x // y`?

Tags: python, casting, integer, division, floor-division

Is there a difference (and if so why?) in python (possibly in rounding) between floor division `x // y` vs division then casting such as `int(x / y)`?

Comment: `print(int(-5/4))` `print(-5//4)` gives `-1` and `-2`

Comment: Are you interested specifically in the case where `x` and `y` have type `int`, or are you also asking about the more general case where `x` and `y` might be `float`s (or `Decimal` instances, or `Fractions`, etc.)?

Comment: Consider also cases like `x = 10**17-1`, `y = 10**17`, where `int(x/y)` gives `1` (on a typical machine) and `x//y` gives `0` (on any machine).

Answer (score 3):

Well yes, as its name indicates `//` *floors* aka rounds towards `-∞`. [`int`, on the other hand](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.

So they will diverge for any division in the negatives.

Comment: It does depend a bit on the types of `x` and `y`; I'm _guessing_ that the OP is working with `int`s, but it's not clear. E.g., `Decimal(-3) // 5 == int(Decimal(-3) / 5)` is true. And if `x` and `y` are `float` objects, there's a whole range of _extra_ ways that this can go wrong, even for positive inputs - e.g., `18.9 // 0.7` versus `int(18.9 / 0.7)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late, but anyways.

Building on others' answers, the most important differnce you'll likely encounter is:

```
>>> -11 // 5
-3
>>> int(-11 / 5)
-2
```

**tl;dr**: These are not the same operations.